# Limpiar datagridview conectado a datos c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, linq, visual-studio-2017

Bien estoy realizando una factura lo cual esa factura consta de dos tablas detalle compra y compra ella guarda y todo perfecto! Mi problema es que al momento que se guardo correctamente si quiero volver hacer una factura sin cerrar el formulario siguen estando los producto que se realizaron en la factura anterior realizada, consto con un boton agregar producto si estan en el textbox el producto lo agregar al grid
utilizo linq para colocar las columna en el datagrid y quiero saber si hay alguna forma

```
 private void ActualizarLista()
    {
        //Nventas gestionproduucto = new Nventas();
        //listaventas = gestionproduucto.obtenerlistventa();
    }
    private void ActualizarLista2()
    {

        //Ndetalleventa gestiondetalle = new Ndetalleventa();
        //listadetalle = gestiondetalle.obtenerlistdetalle();
        var lista = (from d in compra.listadetalle
                     select new
                     {
                         //d.ventas.idventas,
                         d.producto.Codproducto,
                         d.producto.Producto,
                         d.producto.Precio,
                         d.Cantidad,
                         d.Total
                     }).ToList();
        dgvventas.DataSource = lista;




    }


    private void frmCompra_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            ActualizarLista2();




        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }









 private void btnagregar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            EdetalleCompra nuevas = new EdetalleCompra();
            nuevas.Cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(txtCantidad.Text);
            nuevas.producto.Codproducto = Convert.ToInt32(txtproducto.Text);
            nuevas.producto.Precio = Convert.ToDecimal(txtprecio.Text);
            nuevas.Total = Convert.ToDecimal(nuevas.Cantidad * nuevas.producto.Precio);
            nuevas.producto.Producto = txtnombre.Text;
            compra.listadetalle.Add(nuevas);
            ActualizarLista2();
            calculartotal();
            Deshabilitar();
            txtCantidad.Enabled = true;
            btnGuardar.Enabled = true;
            btnCancelar.Enabled = true;
            btnNuevo.Enabled = true;
            txtdescuento.Enabled = true;
            txtproducto.Text = "";
            txtprecio.Text = "";
            txtnombre.Text = "";
            txtCantidad.Text = "";
            txtprecio.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        radioButton2.Enabled = true;
        rbtEfectivo.Enabled = true;
    }



 private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            compra.Proveedor.idProveedor = Convert.ToInt32(txtbuscaridproveedor.Text);
            compra.Usuario.idUsuario = Convert.ToInt32(txtbuscarusuario.Text);
            compra.FechaFactura = dtpfecha.Value;
            compra.HoraFactura = dtpHora.Value;

            if (rbtEfectivo.Checked == true)
            {
                compra.Tipopago = "Efectivo";
            }
            else
            {
                compra.Tipopago = "Tarjeta";

            }
            compra.Subtotal = Convert.ToDecimal(txtsubtotal.Text);
            compra.Descuento = Convert.ToDecimal(txtdescuento.Text);
            compra.TotalCordobas = Convert.ToDecimal(txttotalCordobas.Text);
            compra.TotalDolares = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotalDolares.Text);
            Ncompra gestionventas = new Ncompra();
            gestionventas.agregarcompra(compra);
            MessageBox.Show("Se agrego la compra correctamente", "COMPRA", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            ActualizarLista2();
            Limpiar();
            Deshabilitar();
            btnagregar.Enabled = false;
            btnbuscarcliente.Enabled = false;
            Btnbuscarusuario.Enabled = false;
            txttotalCordobas.Enabled = false;
            txttotalCordobas.Clear();
            txtsubtotal.Clear();

            dgvventas.DataSource = null;
            btnagregar.Enabled = false;
            btnGuardar.Enabled = false;
            btnCancelar.Enabled = false;
            btnNuevo.Enabled = true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }



        Limpiar();

    }
```

Comment: Has probado añadiendo `dgvventas.Rows.Clear();` o `dgvventas.DataBind();` despues de `dgvventas.DataSource = null;`?

Answer (score -1):

Al final del botón ***Guardar*** debes poner el siguiente comando para limpiar el `DataGridView`:

```
dgvventas.Rows.Clear();
```